# ConEmu enable popup window

Tags: configuration, conemu

I am using ConEmu to wrap one of powershell client. Howerver, the popup window in powershell client is blocked by ConEmu. Is there any configuration to enable the popup window in ConEmu?

Comment: They are not blocked. Anyway, why haven't you added your script in the question?

Comment: I don't have any script, just run another app made by powershell client

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/BadIssue.html